# Yet another php date format issue

Tags: php, date, format, strtotime

I have this date format d-m-y on a string so that 01-01-12 is January, 1st of the year 2012.

Now, I want to convert this to a date object in php, to sort a set of dates, which are stored as string in an array.

Currently, I'm using strtotime and date

```
$keypoints[] = date('d-m-y', strtotime($date_str));
```

But this is sorting the resulting dates as if the format is y-m-d. The question is, how can I set the input format of the strtotime function?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the date in `Y-m-d` format

```
$date_arr = explode('-', $date_str);
$keypoints[] = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $date_arr[1], $date_arr[0], $date_arr[2]));
```

Comment: how about this ? $date_arr = explode('-', $date_str);$keypoints[] = date("d-m-y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $date_arr[1], $date_arr[0], $date_arr[2]));

Comment: Then you will get the same input date string as output. `y` gives year in `2` digits and `Y` the full `4` digits. You can use `d-m-Y` if that is what you mean.

Comment: If you are going to use this for sorting, use just the `mktime` part. After sorting you can convert it to your required format.

Answer (score 3):

PHP's strtotime() returns a unix timestamp, which is just a number. Have you considered storing these in your array and sorting like that? You would then convert back to a nice looking date when needed, for example for output.

Answer (score 2):

Dates with backslashes in strtotime are read as m/d/y where as days with - as delimeter are read as d-m-y

From the manual:

> Note:
>
> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)
>   dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. explode() your 01-01-12 date and use the resulting pieces with mktime() to get the correct unixtime.

Comment: You can by using '-' or '.' as your delimiter instead of a backslash

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP manual page, `strtotime` accepts "A date/time string. Valid formats are explained in [Date and Time Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)".

An alternative would be to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).